# System.TypeLoadException while using CsharpRepl (mono shell)

Tags: c#, mono

Before I ditch this c# interpreter I thought I would check if anyone knows what's going wrong here. The type that it complains about is is eloquera.client.dll.

```
c:\Program Files\Mono-2.10.8\bin>csharp
Mono C# Shell, type "help;" for help

Enter statements below.
csharp> LoadAssembly(@"C:\WebApp1\WebApp1\bin\webapp1.dll");
csharp> LoadAssembly(@"C:\WebApp1\WebApp1\bin\eloquera.client.dll");
csharp> using WebApp1.Models.Data_Access;
csharp> using WebApp1.Models.Persisted_classes;
csharp> using Eloquera.Client;
csharp> using System.Linq.Expressions;
csharp>
csharp> var repository = new EloqueraRepository();
csharp> var result = repository.GetAll<CustomMembershipUser>();
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Eloquera.Client.DB' from assembly
 'Eloquera.Client, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=170cadcdba67
be6c'.
  at Class3.Host (System.Object& $retval) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.CSharp.Evaluator.Evaluate (System.String input, System.Object& result,
 System.Boolean& result_set) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.CSharpShell.Evaluate (System.String input) [0x00000] in <filename unkn
own>:0
csharp>
csharp>
csharp>
```

Edit: Focusing in on that problem type:

```
C:\Program Files\Mono-2.11\bin>csharp
Mono C# Shell, type "help;" for help

Enter statements below.
csharp> LoadAssembly(@"C:\WebApp1\WebApp1\bin\webapp1.dll");
csharp> LoadAssembly(@"C:\WebApp1\WebApp1\bin\eloquera.client.dll");
csharp> using WebApp1.Models.Data_Access;
csharp> using WebApp1.Models.Persisted_classes;
csharp> using Eloquera.Client;
csharp> using System.Linq.Expressions;
csharp> string server = "server=localhost;password=pwd;options=none;";
csharp> Console.WriteLine(server);
server=localhost;password=pwd;options=none;
csharp> DB db = new DB(server);
(1,10): error CS0584: Internal compiler error: Unexpected error when loading typ
e `Eloquera.Client.DB'
```

**Edit: Upgraded Eloquera install to EloqueraDatabase CE 4.51 .NET4.0 x32 and tried again. Still not working but perhaps result is a bit more promising:**

```
c:\Program Files\Mono-2.10.8\bin>csharp
Mono C# Shell, type "help;" for help

Enter statements below.
csharp> LoadAssembly(@"C:\WebApp1\WebApp1\bin\webapp1.dll");
csharp> LoadAssembly(@"C:\Program Files\Eloquera\Eloquera Server 4.0\Lib\Eloquer
a.Client.dll");
csharp> using WebApp1.Models.Data_Access;
csharp> using WebApp1.Models.Persisted_classes;
csharp> using System.Linq.Expressions;
csharp> using Eloquera.Client;
csharp>
csharp>
csharp> string server = "server=localhost;password=pwd;options=none;";
csharp> Console.WriteLine(server);
server=localhost;password=pwd;options=none;
csharp> DB db = new DB(server);
csharp> db.OpenDatabase("MockDB");
Eloquera.Client.EloqueraException: The connection to the server localhost on the
 port 43962 cannot be established.

The requested feature is not implemented.
  at Eloquera.Client.DB.OpenConnection () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Eloquera.Client.DB.OpenDatabase (System.String dbName) [0x00000] in <filena
me unknown>:0
  at Class5.Host (System.Object& $retval) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.CSharp.Evaluator.Evaluate (System.String input, System.Object& result,
 System.Boolean& result_set) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.CSharpShell.Evaluate (System.String input) [0x00000] in <filename unkn
own>:0
csharp>
```

Comment: Have you asked Eloquera support? I guess this DLL is compiled for .NET 4 and uses some .NET features which are not compatible with Mono, like Entity Framework.

Comment: So mono doesn't support .Net 4? That could explain it.

Comment: Mono-2.10.8 is *almost* compatible with .NET 4, but there are a few exceptions. Check this out: http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility

Comment: Thx. Some people have managed to use this type (Eloquera.Client.DB) in mono but presumably not in the interpreter: http://eloquera.com/content/mono-compatible   I will look into this more tommorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some TypeLoadException problems in Mono 2.10.x in the past.

I recommend upgrading to Mono 2.11.3 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

Try LoadAssembly(@"C:\WebApp1\WebApp1\bin\Eloquera.Client.dll"); or match to the same case as the namespace.